# Eclipse : Get URL of plug-in's install directory?

Tags: eclipse, plugins, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to revive an application which used **this.getDescriptor().getInstallURL()** and IPluginDescriptor to get the URL path.
Issue:- IPluginDescriptor is not compatible with eclipse version 4.12 and later, so I need an alternative method to get URL of the plugin.

Note: I don't have the resources to change the complete project structure.

Comment: In the activator of the plug-in you can do `FileLocator.getBundleFile(bundleContext.getBundle()).toURI()`. Is that what you're looking for?